# href is not working in App.vue file of vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I given link in href tags. but it is not working as it is present in App.vue file.How to navigate from App.vue file using href??

```
<div v-if="city!=null">
  <f7-page>
    <center>
      <a
        style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;z- 
   index:99;color:#242424;background-color:#FFFFFF;padding:4px 12px; border- 
   radius:40px"
        @click="save"
      >Skip</a>
      <f7-block style="margin:0px">
        <div style="color:gray;font-size: 14px;">Ready to Explore Local World ! </div>
        <div>
          <a
            href="/signup/"
            style="background-color:#273657;margin: 20px 10px 10px 
   10px"
            class="button button-fill button-big"
          ><b>Join Free</b></a>
        </div>
        <div style="color:gray;font-size: 14px;">Have an account?<span>
            <f7-link
              style="color:green;padding:5px"
              href="/login/"
            >Login</f7-link>
          </span>
        </div>
      </f7-block>
    </center>
  </f7-page>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuimg you are using the Vue-Router, you should use the `router-link` component in order to navigate to another route. See https://router.vuejs.org/api/ for more information.

Basically, the router does not work on the server-side (so no HTTP calls get fired when clicking links), but on the client-side. When you click a router-link everything that changes is handled by the vue app (javascript).